# Pods.framework in red, doesn't exist in DerivedData

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to using Cocoapods 0.39.0 for the dependencies of my project. I have followed the steps, but I end up with a red Pods.framework in my project. If I look at the path where XCode 7.2.1 says it should be, it doesn't exist:

/Users/ajmas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-cskuurnzjrcpcxfoyaceaeepshgt/Build/Products/Debug/Pods.framework

I have looked around at other entries in Stackoverflow, but I am not find anything indicating how the framework should be generated.

The contents of my Podfile are:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'myproject' do
    platform :osx, '10.11'
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Any ideas?

Edit, also tried with Cocoapods 1.0.0.beta and no change, even after updating the Podfile to confirm to 'target' being a requirement now.

Comment: Are you using the .xcworkspace rather than the .xcproject? Also which version of CocoaPods are you using?

Comment: Updated question to indicate versions tried. Using .xcodeproj.

Comment: That's your problem then. Open the .xcworkspace file that cocoapods created for you when you ran `pod install`

Comment: That resolves the issue and I'll treat that as the answer. I had not paid attention to the .xcworkspace  being created and needing to use that - thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this happens it's most likely because you are using `<your_project>.xcproject`. When you run `pod install` CocoaPods creates a `<your_project.xcworkspace` file that you need to use to have dependencies installed via CocoaPods be available when compiling.

Comment: how do we fix the issue ?

Answer (score 19):

Build your project with "Generic iOS Device" selected.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me, I spent hours to fix similar issue

Comment: I think you just need to build the project; selecting "Generic iOS Device" doesn't actually make a difference.

Comment: What the heck. This makes absolutely no sense Apple! Thanks for your help @konsti

Comment: Work for me too.