# WatchOS 2 and RealmSwift

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, realm, watchos-2

I have an iOS project with RealmSwift already imported using `Cocoapods`. Now I'd like to use Realm (and only Realm) in my WatchOS 2 extension. While building the project there are almost 200 errors, so I must have missed out something. Here's my podfile and some of the errors:

[image]
Building the RealmSwift scheme also gives the same errors. I have tried cleaning the project in Xcode itself and Derived Data folder.  Is there something I can do?

**SOLUTION:**

Following [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2774#issuecomment-152952662) reinstalling CocoaPods fixed the errors.

Comment: Is this an XCode workspace or project? This may be similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731416/pods-framework-in-red-doesnt-exist-in-deriveddata ?

Comment: I'm using the workspace.

Comment: Could you expand and share one of the errors, so it is clear what it is complaining about.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qPvXb7F.png

Comment: Which version of CocoaPods do you use? Please make sure that you have at least 0.39 installed.

Comment: I do have version 0.39 (1.0.0 beta 6).
Update: adding `Realm` pod (not RealmSwift) didn't fix anything.

Comment: Which XCode version are you using?

Comment: 7.3, but I found the solution, check the question footnote